# Camel file component URI format

Tags: java, apache-camel

Camel file component supports two notations for URI format:

```
file:directoryName[?options]
file://directoryName[?options]
```

Why does the second one exist? It is less readable, especially when using Unix-like absolute paths, which is a frequent use case. In general, should I give preference to one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The // are part of the Camel File Component itself(and also the other camel components). They are optional so u don't have to use it.

In the case of the file component and unix absolute paths you can use file:///directoryName for example.

Comment: Would be interesting if file:/directoryName also works for unix absolute paths.

Comment: Yes, it works with that notation as well. I'm just wondering why double-slash notation exists at all, and whether there are use cases in which they are mandatory.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be just an optional separator and has no other meaning.